# bibtex couldn't open database file

Tags: bibtex, windows

I am using Tex since last a few years and use multiple *.bib files to manage the references. In order to avoid the copies of the bib files, I keep them in the texmf-local directory so that they can be accessed as and when required. I recently moved to Windows 11 and having troubles with the same process which is working fine till Windows 10. Here are the details:

I am adding the bib file to the `main.tex` file as follows:

```
\addbibresource{referencesAmit}
```

[[Note that the error is same if I use add bib resource as follows depending on the usages of `bibtex`/ `biblatex`:

```
\bibliography{referencesAmit}
```

After running `pdflatex` (once) and `bibtex`; the **error message** is:

```
I couldn't open database file referencesAmit.bib
```

The file is available at

```
"C:\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bib\local\referencesAmit.bib"
```

Naturally, I have made sure that the file exists. If I use the absolute path, it works (however, it's not ideal if multiple users are using the same files), i.e.,

`\addbibresource{C:/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib/local/referencesAmit}`

I have also checked `TEXMFHOME` (on Windows 10 and Windows 11) using

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

which results (same on both Windows 10 and Windows 11):

```
C:/Users/amit2/texmf
```

I have tried to move the files to this folder, however, the error is the same.

I have also tried to change the `TEXMFHOME` in `texmf.cnf` file, however, there is no change in the output.

I am using `texlive 2021` on `Windows 11` and tried to run both on `TexStudio` and command line (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Comment: what exactly are you doing here? You haven't told us any details about your document. My quess is that you are using `biblatex` and that is it configured to use `biber` (default) not `bibtex`. So use `biber` and not `bibtex` to generate your bibliography

Comment: It should be `\addbibresource{referencesAmit.bib}` with the extension. But apart from this, are files found at all from your texmf-local? (And do you really use wsl?)

Comment: @daleif, the problem persists if I use `bibtex` or `biblatex`. Since the problem is more of a system dependent, there is no MWE.
@UlrikeFischer, as per my information, the bib resource would be without extension. It is able to find another script (`texcount.pl`) in the `texmf-local` but not the bib files. I am using WSL but calling the installation in the Windows C drive. Something like `/mnt/c/texlive/2021/bin/win32/bibexport.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. Here is the solution which worked for me. Based on many reads, it can be helpful for others.

I was right to check the `TEXMFHOME` using (`kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`). It results in

```
C:/Users/amit2/texmf
```

Earlier, I moved the bib file to this location, which was not working correctly. I should have followed the TDS, i.e., moved the files to

```
C:/Users/amit2/texmf/bibtex/bib/local
```

I had to create the folders. Then it worked as expected.